# Increment and Decrement item quantity based on Id in angular/Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am working on an `ionic` e-commerce application. I have an issue: when I increment or decrement a 'carted' item, it increments or decrements all the other items. I don't know how to resolve this.

```
<ion-content class="bg-color">
  <ion-list no-lines>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let lstproduct of lstproductdetail">
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="{{ lstproduct.image_url }}" />
      </ion-avatar>
      <h3>{{ lstproduct.name }}</h3>
      <p class="d-flex">
        Exp. Delivery by Sun, June 11
        <span class="end">{{ lstproduct.price }}</span>
      </p>
          <div class="quantity control-group123">
              <label class="required">Quantity</label>
            <input value="-"  (click)="decrementItem(Itemquantity)" 
         readonly="readonly" class="uk-input tm-quantity-input quantity-change"
          style="width: 35px; border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;">
         <input  value="{{Itemquantity}}"  readonly="readonly" 
         class="uk-input tm-quantity-input quantity-change"
         style="width: 60px; position: relative; margin-left: -4px; margin-right: -4px; border-right: none; 
         border-left: none; border-radius: 0px;">
        <input value="+" (click)="addItem(Itemquantity)" 
         readonly="readonly" class="uk-input tm-quantity-input quantity-change" 
         style="width: 35px; padding: 0px 12px; 
         border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;">
         </div>
          <div style="margin-left: 75px">
              <button ion-button  class="btn shadow" (click)="removeitem(lstproduct.id)">
                  Remove Item <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
               </button>
          </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

.ts file code:

```
addItem(value: any) {
    const initialvalue = 0;
    if (value != null) {
        const afterclick = value + 1;
        return (this.Itemquantity = afterclick);
    }
    else {
        return (this.Itemquantity = initialvalue + 1);
    }
}

decrementItem(value: any) { 
    const initialvalue = 1;
    if (value > 0) {
        const afterclick = value - 1;
        return (this.Itemquantity = afterclick);
    }
    else {
        return (this.Itemquantity = initialvalue - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: .ts file cod eaddItem(value: any) {
    const initialvalue = 0;
    if (value != null) {
      const afterclick = value + 1;
      return (this.Itemquantity = afterclick);
    } else {
      return (this.Itemquantity = initialvalue + 1);
    }
  }

  decrementItem(value: any) {
    const initialvalue = 1;
    if (value > 0) {
      const afterclick = value - 1;
      return (this.Itemquantity = afterclick);
    } else {
      return (this.Itemquantity = initialvalue - 1);
    }
  }

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-sy3twv

Comment: I 'moved' the code you added as a comment into the question itself. This is what ***you*** are supposed to do!

Comment: @Adrian thanks alot for your concern i have already resolved this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am supposing that `lstproductdetail` is the name of the array that all the products and `lstproduct` is how you show one product's data.

In such case, the quantity of your product should not be shown as a common property `Itemquantity`. The quantity should differ and should be unique for each product. For eg, `lstproduct.quantity` (the same way you are showing different price for each different product).

Similarly then, when you'll increment the quantity you can pass a unique id of the object lstproduct in the function and can increment this particular object's quantity. I am going to show you how to do this with index.

Eg,

In HTML:

Change - `<ion-item *ngFor="let lstproduct of lstproductdetail; let i=index">`

In TS:

```
eaddItem(value: any, i) { 
     const initialvalue = 0; 
     if (value != null) { 
         const afterclick = value + 1; 
         return (this.lstproductdetail[i].Itemquantity = afterclick); 
     } 
     else { 
         return (this.lstproductdetail[i].Itemquantity = initialvalue + 1); 
     } 
} 

decrementItem(value: any, i) { 
    const initialvalue = 1; 
    if (value > 0) { 
        const afterclick = value - 1; 
        return (this.lstproductdetail[i].Itemquantity = afterclick); 
    } 
    else { 
        return (this.lstproductdetail[i].Itemquantity = initialvalue - 1); 
    } 
}
```

This way, the quantity will change for only the product this function is called on.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set property 'Itemquantity' of undefined
    at CartPage.webpackJsonp.47.CartPage.addItem (cart.ts:65)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (CartPage.html:33)

Comment: getting above error while i use your code but when i run my own its working

Comment: return (this.lstproductdetail[i].Itemquantity = afterclick);  this line is getting problem

Comment: How have you declared lstproductdetail in your component ts ?

Comment: Did you add i to your function call in HTML as well? you need to change the function call as (click)="decrementItem(Itemquantity, i)" and (click)="addItem(Itemquantity, i)"

Comment: done by myself. i just added (lstproductdetail[i].Itemquantity,i) in my .html file from where i am calling this method its working properly. Thanks for your precious time and comment

Comment: I am glad I could help you. Please do vote my answer as the correct one. Thanks.

Comment: may i ask something elese of sametype because i cant post other question till next 90 minutes

Comment: i am asking to you madam

Comment: its ok no problem. Take your time